# Configure HTTPS proxy on iPad

Tags: ipad, network, safari, proxy

I have a secure login page on my localhost. In my network settings on the iPad I can only change HTTP proxy setting to access insecure pages in localhost.

I have configured it this way:
Server: 192.168.1.5
Port: 80

but when I want access https://localhost/api, Safari warns:

> There was a problem communicating with the secure web proxy server (HTTPS).

How can I configure for HTTPS proxy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951052/proxy-the-http-and-https-traffic-from-my-iphone-ipad-to-virtualbox-on-my-mac

Comment: Is your situation analogous to this [report of a user using charles proxy?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/147896/5472)

Comment: Just wondering if you tried the port for https with these settings? Server: 192.168.1.5
Port: 443

Answer (score -2):

to listen https request on your server,server need listening on port 443.for listening the traffic of 443 and 80 you need to perform routing and then for example listening on port 8080 after redirect all traffic on 8080.